# How to show the tooltip value based on condition using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

How can I show some text for the column transfer which has the values 0 / 1, like if the value is 0 text on tooltip should be 'activated', if the value is 1 the text should be 'not activated'

Below is the logic I wrote but it's not working please suggest me the right changes.

```
<span *ngIf = "headerDef['property'][i] === 'transfer' "
title="{{headerDef['transfer'][i] == '0' ? headerDef['transfer'][i]: 'Activated' }}
{{ headerDef['transfer'][i] == '0' ? headerDef['transfer'][i]: 'Not Activated' }}"
>
</span>
```

Comment: **(1.)** 0/1 !== Boolean. **(2.)** In the condition you're comparing against string `'0'`. That makes a huge difference. `!!0 === false` while `!!'0' === true`. So what is the correct condition?

Comment: @MichaelD it's type string, not Boolean

Comment: @MichaelD but still it shows 0 in the tooltip

Comment: I've posted a working example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atf9y7?file=src/app/app.component.ts) in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your comment into account (comparison against a string), you could use a single ternary operator.

Try the following

```html
<span 
  *ngIf="headerDef['property'][i] === 'transfer'"
  [title]="headerDef['transfer'][i] == '0' ? 'Activated' : 'Not Activated'"
>
</span>
```

Note that we assume if the value is `'0'` it *must* be `'1'` and display `'Not Activated'`. It there are additional values that needs to be checked, the ternary operator needs to be expanded.

**Update:** Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atf9y7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)